# React: update nested collections with an index variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

According to the docs of Update add-on, we can do the following:

```
var collection = [1, 2, {a: [12, 17, 15]}];
var newCollection = update(collection, {2: {a: {$splice: [[1, 1, 13, 14]]}}});
// => [1, 2, {a: [12, 13, 14, 15]}]
```

This accesses collection's index 2, key a, and does a splice of one item starting from index 1 (to remove 17) while inserting 13 and 14.

Is it able to use a variable for the index field, say:

```
var indexOfA = (certain conditions) ? 0 : 1;
var newCollection = update(collection, { indexOfA: {a: {$splice: [[1, 1, 13, 14]]}}});
```

Thank you.

Comment: did you try it? what happens?

Comment: Not the way you have written it. JavaScript object keys can be strings or numbers. If you want to evaluate a variable use dynamic key syntax `var x = 'foo', ob = { [x]: 'bar' }`

Comment: Couldn't compile with Babel using my original form. Will try the above suggestion. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your index variable in square brackets does the trick:

```
var newCollection = update(collection, { [indexOfA]: {a: {$splice: [[1, 1, 13, 14]]}}});
```